# Pruning a large table based on the results from a smaller table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to understand if I can reduce the number of partitions scanned in the following scenario.

I have two tables:

```
Table A (100M rows)
JOIN_KEY   DATA_1    DATA_2  etc.

Table B  (40K rows)
JOIN_KEY   FILTER_COL_A    FILTER_COL_B
```

When a user wants to query data from Table A, they need to get the corresponding `JOIN_KEY` values from Table B by filtering on `FILTER_COL_A` & `FILTER_COL_B`.

When filtering on `FILTER_COL_A` & `FILTER_COL_B` it will produce a very smaller number of values for `JOIN_KEY` - typically only 3, but could be more.

Table A is clustered by `JOIN_KEY`.

When I write a query joining both tables on JOIN_KEY and then filtering on `FILTER_COL_A` and `FILTER_COL_B`, all partitions on Table A are scanned instead of approximately 5 partitions out of 800.

I can't directly filter on the JOIN_KEY as at run-time, I wont know what values this should be until the data is returned from Table B.

Is there a way I can structure the query so Snowflake would use the results from Table B in a join filter and prune most of the partitions of Table A?

Comment: Snowflake partition prunes on joins if it can. One reason it can't is if the data is not clustered by the join keys on the tables, particularly the larger one. Have you run SYSTEM$CLUSTERING_INFORMATION on the join keys? If you see the results down by the bottom of the histogram, you may need to run the auto clustering service to benefit from pruning on this join.

Comment: Auto clustering is enabled on the larger table and clustered by the join key.  SYSTEM$CLUSTERING_INFORMATION goes no futher than 00007 with average depth of 3.0878.

The smaller table doesnt have a clustering key defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this answer in case anyone else comes up against this.

It appears that at the time of writing it only works when you have a datatype of `number(38,0)` for the `JOIN_KEY` column on both Table A and Table B.

When `number (38,0)` is used, Snowflake prunes the paritions on Table A based on the results of Table B after filtering with `FILTER_COL_A` and `FILTER_COL_B`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming INNER JOIN and depending on where you are performing filtering, options include
a) putting the filters in the WHERE clause
or
b) putting them in the JOIN clause (not clear if this is what you are saying you can't do).
or
c)A.JOIN_KEY IN (SELECT JOIN_KEY FROM B WHERE ...)

Best advice I can give with current information.

Comment: At run time, we dont know what the values of `JOIN_KEY` from Table A should be, so they cant be supplied in either the JOIN or WHERE clauses.  Table B is essentially a lookup table which returns the keys required based on the user's requests

Answer (score 0):

Pruning is done at SQL compile time based on looking at the meta data for the partitions.

Given you are joining the two tables, only the partitions of Table B can be pruned and the filter clauses are known.

Therefore you ether need to write you result of your table B query to a temp table and then join on temp table and table A.

OR

Your Table A should have `FILTER_COL_A`, `FILTER_COL_B` as columns, and have the table clustered by `(FILTER_COL_A,FILTER_COL_B)`, then you can query this table directly.

I would suggest testing this for yourself, by making a new Table A' with those columns and doing a test against it to see the pruning in play.

Comment: Adding `FILTER_COL_A` and `FILTER_COL_B` to table A increases the row count significantly as its a 1:M relationship.  The table would go from 100M to ~7B and maintaining it would be an issue.  I'd like to avoid doing that if I can.

A temp table is an option, but getting it to work with the BI tool (Tableau) may be a problem.

Comment: @suchafunkymonkey at one level it seems strange that is possible for filters that return ~3 rows to have 70x effect on the base table. Again, I suggest to try it and see if it still performs better or not. If it has zero positive impact then you know.. once you know we can make you reads "faster" or "cheaper" you can workout with the increase in "costs" for maintaining it is. And pick the price performance that is the most acceptable. We have many tables with 12+B rows, that are dups of the base table, but with cut down columns to get the advantage of pruning. because we tested, and it worked