# Q: How do I filter a large table based on a few values in a smaller table and not scan entire large table?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a small lookup table and I want to filter a lager table by a few values UUID values in the lookup table.  I’ve been struggling to not scan the entire larger table.  So far I’ve only been able use a subset of partitions from the larger table if I hard code my filter values in the where statement.   This doesn’t seem right, what am I missing?

The example below sets up sample data and provides three examples of filtering the larger tag value table.  As shown by the partitionsAssigned and bytesAssigned numbers only Example 3 is scanning part of the partitions.

Data Setup

```
// Dummy reference table to map PATHUUID to a PATH, 20 rows
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE  TAGMAP (PATHUUID TEXT, PATH TEXT, PATHTYPE TEXT) ;
INSERT INTO TAGMAP SELECT '28da4f4a-4ede-5482-a6b4-614f7ae32589', 'PATH1', 'TYPE1';
INSERT INTO TAGMAP SELECT '612a7e20-7f73-57ae-a427-1bd6a06790b1', 'PATH2', 'TYPE1';
INSERT INTO TAGMAP SELECT 'e0a2ba9c-f833-5d8c-94c7-e9e5504ae59b', 'PATH3', 'TYPE1';
INSERT INTO TAGMAP SELECT 'b8e5a1eb-555b-50bc-b68a-c91201c66979', 'PATH4', 'TYPE2';
INSERT INTO TAGMAP SELECT '1ae3a8b7-02e1-53a8-a88e-cb72fce8d6a4', 'PATH5', 'TYPE2';
INSERT INTO TAGMAP SELECT '2e7105f3-3d71-5601-9366-00fa5efb43e3', 'PATH6', 'TYPE2';
INSERT INTO TAGMAP SELECT '5cdb2715-cf76-5f6b-a3c8-ce1b34d2f34c', 'PATH7', 'TYPE3';
INSERT INTO TAGMAP SELECT '521d5cd6-d324-500c-8d1b-8132fc08a781', 'PATH8', 'TYPE4';
INSERT INTO TAGMAP SELECT '2c56928f-6832-5028-b760-b6480da38463', 'PATH9', 'TYPE5';
INSERT INTO TAGMAP SELECT '6ba4b93e-1280-5dcd-afb7-656283cc74e9', 'PATH10', 'TYPE6';
INSERT INTO TAGMAP SELECT 'c5378f1f-8d5b-5e05-9caf-127d80b3ceb8', 'PATH11', 'TYPE7';
INSERT INTO TAGMAP SELECT '389a885f-61c6-55d0-9cd3-874ae1c242a5', 'PATH12', 'TYPE8';
INSERT INTO TAGMAP SELECT '71715578-fa01-5497-841a-b874ba758ffb', 'PATH13', 'TYPE9';
INSERT INTO TAGMAP SELECT '321296da-6c4a-51f0-8c2b-db5a6de400c2', 'PATH14', 'TYPE10';
INSERT INTO TAGMAP SELECT '28824be8-bace-5be5-8ff0-80135a27ffd4', 'PATH15', 'TYPE10';
INSERT INTO TAGMAP SELECT '1e37be24-3753-5418-8163-9eead501d343', 'PATH16', 'TYPE10';
INSERT INTO TAGMAP SELECT 'f4de2248-690d-574e-b1f6-412180ae5d23', 'PATH17', 'TYPE13';
INSERT INTO TAGMAP SELECT '40c04ed3-0301-5cd8-91ae-530976e426b2', 'PATH18', 'TYPE14';
INSERT INTO TAGMAP SELECT '57cbc90e-a441-5118-9d2c-aff510c770b5', 'PATH19', 'TYPE15';
INSERT INTO TAGMAP SELECT '81c01629-55f7-5266-abf0-f4ecafc4b0be', 'PATH20', 'TYPE16';

// Dummy data table with a PATHUUID to map back to TAGMAP table 200,000,000 rows
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE  TAGVALUES (PATHUUID TEXT, VALUE INT) ;
INSERT INTO TAGVALUES SELECT '28da4f4a-4ede-5482-a6b4-614f7ae32589' as PATHUUID, uniform(1, 9999, random(12)) from table(generator(rowcount => 10000000)) v order by 2;
INSERT INTO TAGVALUES SELECT '612a7e20-7f73-57ae-a427-1bd6a06790b1' as PATHUUID, uniform(1, 9999, random(12)) from table(generator(rowcount => 10000000)) v order by 2;
INSERT INTO TAGVALUES SELECT 'e0a2ba9c-f833-5d8c-94c7-e9e5504ae59b' as PATHUUID, uniform(1, 9999, random(12)) from table(generator(rowcount => 10000000)) v order by 2;
INSERT INTO TAGVALUES SELECT 'b8e5a1eb-555b-50bc-b68a-c91201c66979' as PATHUUID, uniform(1, 9999, random(12)) from table(generator(rowcount => 10000000)) v order by 2;
INSERT INTO TAGVALUES SELECT '1ae3a8b7-02e1-53a8-a88e-cb72fce8d6a4' as PATHUUID, uniform(1, 9999, random(12)) from table(generator(rowcount => 10000000)) v order by 2;
INSERT INTO TAGVALUES SELECT '2e7105f3-3d71-5601-9366-00fa5efb43e3' as PATHUUID, uniform(1, 9999, random(12)) from table(generator(rowcount => 10000000)) v order by 2;
INSERT INTO TAGVALUES SELECT '5cdb2715-cf76-5f6b-a3c8-ce1b34d2f34c' as PATHUUID, uniform(1, 9999, random(12)) from table(generator(rowcount => 10000000)) v order by 2;
INSERT INTO TAGVALUES SELECT '521d5cd6-d324-500c-8d1b-8132fc08a781' as PATHUUID, uniform(1, 9999, random(12)) from table(generator(rowcount => 10000000)) v order by 2;
INSERT INTO TAGVALUES SELECT '2c56928f-6832-5028-b760-b6480da38463' as PATHUUID, uniform(1, 9999, random(12)) from table(generator(rowcount => 10000000)) v order by 2;
INSERT INTO TAGVALUES SELECT '6ba4b93e-1280-5dcd-afb7-656283cc74e9' as PATHUUID, uniform(1, 9999, random(12)) from table(generator(rowcount => 10000000)) v order by 2;
INSERT INTO TAGVALUES SELECT 'c5378f1f-8d5b-5e05-9caf-127d80b3ceb8' as PATHUUID, uniform(1, 9999, random(12)) from table(generator(rowcount => 10000000)) v order by 2;
INSERT INTO TAGVALUES SELECT '389a885f-61c6-55d0-9cd3-874ae1c242a5' as PATHUUID, uniform(1, 9999, random(12)) from table(generator(rowcount => 10000000)) v order by 2;
INSERT INTO TAGVALUES SELECT '71715578-fa01-5497-841a-b874ba758ffb' as PATHUUID, uniform(1, 9999, random(12)) from table(generator(rowcount => 10000000)) v order by 2;
INSERT INTO TAGVALUES SELECT '321296da-6c4a-51f0-8c2b-db5a6de400c2' as PATHUUID, uniform(1, 9999, random(12)) from table(generator(rowcount => 10000000)) v order by 2;
INSERT INTO TAGVALUES SELECT '28824be8-bace-5be5-8ff0-80135a27ffd4' as PATHUUID, uniform(1, 9999, random(12)) from table(generator(rowcount => 10000000)) v order by 2;
INSERT INTO TAGVALUES SELECT '1e37be24-3753-5418-8163-9eead501d343' as PATHUUID, uniform(1, 9999, random(12)) from table(generator(rowcount => 10000000)) v order by 2;
INSERT INTO TAGVALUES SELECT 'f4de2248-690d-574e-b1f6-412180ae5d23' as PATHUUID, uniform(1, 9999, random(12)) from table(generator(rowcount => 10000000)) v order by 2;
INSERT INTO TAGVALUES SELECT '40c04ed3-0301-5cd8-91ae-530976e426b2' as PATHUUID, uniform(1, 9999, random(12)) from table(generator(rowcount => 10000000)) v order by 2;
INSERT INTO TAGVALUES SELECT '57cbc90e-a441-5118-9d2c-aff510c770b5' as PATHUUID, uniform(1, 9999, random(12)) from table(generator(rowcount => 10000000)) v order by 2;
INSERT INTO TAGVALUES SELECT '81c01629-55f7-5266-abf0-f4ecafc4b0be' as PATHUUID, uniform(1, 9999, random(12)) from table(generator(rowcount => 10000000)) v order by 2;

// For the example below we have 3 target PATHUUIDs
SELECT PATHUUID FROM TAGMAP t where t.PATHTYPE = 'TYPE10'
```

Example 1, full table scan

```
// -- Example 1, use join on PATHUUID to find count
// -- Scans entire TAGVALUES table
// -- partitionsTotal: 41
// -- partitionsAssigned: 41
// -- bytesAssigned: 295827968
EXPLAIN 
SELECT count(*)
FROM TAGVALUES v
left join TAGMAP t
on v.PATHUUID = t.PATHUUID
WHERE t.PATHTYPE = 'TYPE10'
```

Example 2, full table scan

```
// -- Example 2, use CTE join on PATHUUID to find count
// -- Scans entire TAGVALUES table
// -- partitionsTotal: 41
// -- partitionsAssigned: 41
// -- bytesAssigned: 295827968
EXPLAIN 
with PATHUUIDFilter as 
(SELECT PATHUUID FROM TAGMAP t where t.PATHTYPE = 'TYPE10')
SELECT count(*)
FROM PATHUUIDFilter f
left join TAGVALUES v
on f.PATHUUID = v.PATHUUID
```

Example 3, 15% of partitions scanned

```
// -- Example 3, hard code PATHUUID to find count
// -- Scans 6/40 partitions in  TAGVALUES table
// -- partitionsTotal: 40
// -- partitionsAssigned: 6
// -- bytesAssigned: 44362752
EXPLAIN 
SELECT count(*)
FROM TAGVALUES v
where v.PATHUUID in (
'321296da-6c4a-51f0-8c2b-db5a6de400c2',
'28824be8-bace-5be5-8ff0-80135a27ffd4',
'1e37be24-3753-5418-8163-9eead501d343'
)
```

Thank you

Comment: Snowflake does static partition pruning at compile time using eligible predicates in the where clause. It will do dynamic pruning, which is less effective, at execution time. Pruning on join keys like UUIDs often does not lead to a situation that will prune on joins. Incremental numbers work better sometimes, as you noted. If you're just looking for a small number of UUIDs, the IN clause in your WHERE filter will be the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Your left join tells the query engine to join all records from TAGVALUES to TAGMAP and records in the TAGVALUES do not have to match so the query is scanning the full table

Without seeing the query profile I would suggest the where clause is likely being evaluated after this step.

Try using just JOIN and possibly add the where the condition to the join clause. Adding the condition to the join clause probably won't make a difference though but worth testing

Comment: Thank you, converting LEFT JOIN to JOIN had no effect.  However when I posted this I did find this hint that columns had to be number (38,0).  I'll post an update, it appears if I convert the PATHUUID join column to number (38,0) all three examples work as expected.
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66820151/pruning-a-large-table-based-on-the-results-from-a-smaller-table

Answer (score 0):

When I posted the above I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66820151/pruning-a-large-table-based-on-the-results-from-a-smaller-table) question stating that the joins had to be number (38,0) to work in his example.  I've updated my sample to use md5_number_upper64 rather than uuid_string's and all three examples work as expected. I'll need to look into this more but it appears to solve my issue for the example.

Updated samples working
Data setup

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE  TAGMAP (PATHUUID number (38,0), PATH TEXT, PATHTYPE TEXT) ;

TRUNCATE TABLE  TAGMAP;
INSERT INTO TAGMAP SELECT md5_number_upper64('PATH1'), 'PATH1', 'TYPE1';
INSERT INTO TAGMAP SELECT md5_number_upper64('PATH2'), 'PATH2', 'TYPE1';
INSERT INTO TAGMAP SELECT md5_number_upper64('PATH3'), 'PATH3', 'TYPE1';
INSERT INTO TAGMAP SELECT md5_number_upper64('PATH4'), 'PATH4', 'TYPE2';
INSERT INTO TAGMAP SELECT md5_number_upper64('PATH5'), 'PATH5', 'TYPE2';
INSERT INTO TAGMAP SELECT md5_number_upper64('PATH6'), 'PATH6', 'TYPE2';
INSERT INTO TAGMAP SELECT md5_number_upper64('PATH7'), 'PATH7', 'TYPE3';
INSERT INTO TAGMAP SELECT md5_number_upper64('PATH8'), 'PATH8', 'TYPE4';
INSERT INTO TAGMAP SELECT md5_number_upper64('PATH9'), 'PATH9', 'TYPE5';
INSERT INTO TAGMAP SELECT md5_number_upper64('PATH10'), 'PATH10', 'TYPE6';
INSERT INTO TAGMAP SELECT md5_number_upper64('PATH11'), 'PATH11', 'TYPE7';
INSERT INTO TAGMAP SELECT md5_number_upper64('PATH12'), 'PATH12', 'TYPE8';
INSERT INTO TAGMAP SELECT md5_number_upper64('PATH13'), 'PATH13', 'TYPE9';
INSERT INTO TAGMAP SELECT md5_number_upper64('PATH14'), 'PATH14', 'TYPE10';
INSERT INTO TAGMAP SELECT md5_number_upper64('PATH15'), 'PATH15', 'TYPE10';
INSERT INTO TAGMAP SELECT md5_number_upper64('PATH16'), 'PATH16', 'TYPE10';
INSERT INTO TAGMAP SELECT md5_number_upper64('PATH17'), 'PATH17', 'TYPE13';
INSERT INTO TAGMAP SELECT md5_number_upper64('PATH18'), 'PATH18', 'TYPE14';
INSERT INTO TAGMAP SELECT md5_number_upper64('PATH19'), 'PATH19', 'TYPE15';
INSERT INTO TAGMAP SELECT md5_number_upper64('PATH20'), 'PATH20', 'TYPE16';


CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE  TAGVALUES (PATHUUID  number (38,0), VALUE INT) ;

TRUNCATE TABLE  TAGVALUES;
INSERT INTO TAGVALUES SELECT md5_number_upper64('PATH1') as PATHUUID, uniform(1, 9999, random(12)) from table(generator(rowcount => 10000000)) v order by 2;
INSERT INTO TAGVALUES SELECT md5_number_upper64('PATH2') as PATHUUID, uniform(1, 9999, random(12)) from table(generator(rowcount => 10000000)) v order by 2;
INSERT INTO TAGVALUES SELECT md5_number_upper64('PATH3') as PATHUUID, uniform(1, 9999, random(12)) from table(generator(rowcount => 10000000)) v order by 2;
INSERT INTO TAGVALUES SELECT md5_number_upper64('PATH4') as PATHUUID, uniform(1, 9999, random(12)) from table(generator(rowcount => 10000000)) v order by 2;
INSERT INTO TAGVALUES SELECT md5_number_upper64('PATH5') as PATHUUID, uniform(1, 9999, random(12)) from table(generator(rowcount => 10000000)) v order by 2;
INSERT INTO TAGVALUES SELECT md5_number_upper64('PATH6') as PATHUUID, uniform(1, 9999, random(12)) from table(generator(rowcount => 10000000)) v order by 2;
INSERT INTO TAGVALUES SELECT md5_number_upper64('PATH7') as PATHUUID, uniform(1, 9999, random(12)) from table(generator(rowcount => 10000000)) v order by 2;
INSERT INTO TAGVALUES SELECT md5_number_upper64('PATH8') as PATHUUID, uniform(1, 9999, random(12)) from table(generator(rowcount => 10000000)) v order by 2;
INSERT INTO TAGVALUES SELECT md5_number_upper64('PATH9') as PATHUUID, uniform(1, 9999, random(12)) from table(generator(rowcount => 10000000)) v order by 2;
INSERT INTO TAGVALUES SELECT md5_number_upper64('PATH10') as PATHUUID, uniform(1, 9999, random(12)) from table(generator(rowcount => 10000000)) v order by 2;
INSERT INTO TAGVALUES SELECT md5_number_upper64('PATH11') as PATHUUID, uniform(1, 9999, random(12)) from table(generator(rowcount => 10000000)) v order by 2;
INSERT INTO TAGVALUES SELECT md5_number_upper64('PATH12') as PATHUUID, uniform(1, 9999, random(12)) from table(generator(rowcount => 10000000)) v order by 2;
INSERT INTO TAGVALUES SELECT md5_number_upper64('PATH13') as PATHUUID, uniform(1, 9999, random(12)) from table(generator(rowcount => 10000000)) v order by 2;
INSERT INTO TAGVALUES SELECT md5_number_upper64('PATH14') as PATHUUID, uniform(1, 9999, random(12)) from table(generator(rowcount => 10000000)) v order by 2;
INSERT INTO TAGVALUES SELECT md5_number_upper64('PATH15') as PATHUUID, uniform(1, 9999, random(12)) from table(generator(rowcount => 10000000)) v order by 2;
INSERT INTO TAGVALUES SELECT md5_number_upper64('PATH16') as PATHUUID, uniform(1, 9999, random(12)) from table(generator(rowcount => 10000000)) v order by 2;
INSERT INTO TAGVALUES SELECT md5_number_upper64('PATH17') as PATHUUID, uniform(1, 9999, random(12)) from table(generator(rowcount => 10000000)) v order by 2;
INSERT INTO TAGVALUES SELECT md5_number_upper64('PATH18') as PATHUUID, uniform(1, 9999, random(12)) from table(generator(rowcount => 10000000)) v order by 2;
INSERT INTO TAGVALUES SELECT md5_number_upper64('PATH19') as PATHUUID, uniform(1, 9999, random(12)) from table(generator(rowcount => 10000000)) v order by 2;
INSERT INTO TAGVALUES SELECT md5_number_upper64('PATH20') as PATHUUID, uniform(1, 9999, random(12)) from table(generator(rowcount => 10000000)) v order by 2;

// three rows
SELECT PATHUUID FROM TAGMAP t where t.PATHTYPE = 'TYPE10'
```

Example 1

```
// -- Example 1, use join on PATHUUID to find count
// -- Scans entire TAGVALUES table
// -- partitionsTotal: 41
// -- partitionsAssigned: 1
// -- bytesAssigned: 2048
EXPLAIN 
SELECT count(*)
FROM TAGVALUES v
left join TAGMAP t
on v.PATHUUID = t.PATHUUID
WHERE t.PATHTYPE = 'TYPE10'
```

Example 2

```
// -- Example 2, use CTE join on PATHUUID to find count
// -- Scans entire TAGVALUES table
// -- partitionsTotal: 41
// -- partitionsAssigned: 1
// -- bytesAssigned: 2048
EXPLAIN 
with PATHUUIDFilter as 
(SELECT PATHUUID FROM TAGMAP t where t.PATHTYPE = 'TYPE10')
SELECT count(*)
FROM PATHUUIDFilter f
left join TAGVALUES v
on f.PATHUUID = v.PATHUUID
```

Example 3

```
// -- Example 3, hard code PATHUUID to find count
// -- Scans 6/40 partitions in  TAGVALUES table
// -- partitionsTotal: 40
// -- partitionsAssigned: 0
// -- bytesAssigned: 0
EXPLAIN 
SELECT count(*)
FROM TAGVALUES v
where v.PATHUUID in (
5944718881441917065,
3379648765010274384,
4532955584134004551
)
```

Comment: It's possible that joining on a string is taking longer due to partial string matching so converting to an int as you have above would solve that. However, just be careful of possible collisions if you are using this as a unique identifier. I've also read that storing the hash result as a binary type is even more performant but I haven't done it personally so can't confirm